# Finding solution curves for $y'=\max(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone provide the solution curves for the differential equation $y'=\max(x,y)$? Or tell me the commands necessary for input in Mathematica or Maple?

Comment: Hint: separate the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y\ge x$ then $y'=y$. Then $y(x)=A e^x$.

If $y<x$ then $y'=x$. Then $y(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$.

You must look where is the initial condition and be aware of the phase changes ($y=x$).

Comment: Thanks for the correction Christian.